# Correct Rails way to CRUD extra attributes on link table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, many-to-many, nested-attributes

I have an extra `position` attribute on my many-to-many link table. Its purpose is to define hand-ordered position of an `Item` in a `Group`. The link model is called `ItemGroupMembership`.

I am allowing the user to edit this by jQuery UI sortables in a Backbone application.

What is the correct way to update this attribute. Do I treat the link table like a regular model and have a `item_group_memberships_controller`?

Answer (score 0):

How are Item's assigned to Groups in the first place?
This should be done in the `item_group_memberships_controller`.

So,

```
class ItemGroupMembershipsController < Applicationontroller

 def create
   #create the relationship, passing in :position
 end

 def update
    #update the relationship by updating position 
 end

end
```